# what's the appropriate algorithm for locating places using Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: mysql, algorithm

what's the algorithm to be able locate and display places around me within a particular distance such as 100m,using easting and northing and name of the place where I'm based .
To be more clear, lets suppose I'm based in charing cross and I want to find  all places within 100m using easting and northing data for example, easting =10000m and easting=20000m.
Thank you

Comment: Which db are you using? SQL Server (a database by Microsoft) or sqlite?

Comment: mysql.Im trying to find the right formula then use sql for it

Comment: I ask because SQL Server has had spatial capabilities built into it since SQL 2008. If you're using that, you can leverage those capabilities and make your job vastly more simple (and potentially more performant).

Answer (score 1):

[Pythagoras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) is the relevant maths.

If your position is (x,y) then you can calc a distance to any other point (x2,y2) with:

```
distance = sqrt((x2-x)^2 + (y2-y)^2)
```

So you could just loop over all points, calc their distance and order the results by nearest first.

For large data sets this may become impractical, in which case you'll want to partition the points into large rectangles. The first stage then is to identify which rectangle your (x,y) is within and the adjacent rectangles, then loop through all points in those rectangles. You need the adjacent rectangles because your (x,y) might be right on the boundary of its rectangle.

More generally this partitioning approach comes under the general heading of spatial hashing. For very large areas you want a tree structure known as a quadtree, that breaks large areas down into smaller and smaller regions, but that might be overkill for what you want.

Comment: thx for your reply,but in this case I should know the second point to be able to apply but in my case I only know that the second point is  within 100m,which obviously is not gonna be one place only but many places within this range of 100m starting from the point I know that have 10000 easting and 20000 northing.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Note that Northings and Eastings are coords in a grid system in which each unit is 1 meter, so the use of pythagoras is valid. If instead you had lat/long coords then those would need translating to grid coords first (because the units describe different distances depending on where you are), and the maths for that is non-trivial, although I assume there are standard libs for doing it.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming by Cartesian coordinates you also mean linear.  If you are trying to do this using actual earth coordinates this answer gets more complicated (as we aren't on a flat earth).  For simple linear coordinates you could do something like:

```
bool contains( x, y) 
{
   return (x >= minx) && (x <= maxx) && (y >= miny) && (y <= maxy);
}
```

The min, max coordinates would be your current position + how far out you wanted to go.  I think this is what you wanted to know.  If you need accurate earth coordinates you might look into some geospatial libraries.  If you need and estimate you can still use the algorithm above but I would use something like Rhumb lines to calculate the min, max coordinates.

Comment: This does not compute a particular distance.